# Changing the order of Folders and Leaf nodes in ExtJs 4.0 TreePanel

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

In ExtJs 4.0 Tree Panel the folders always appears first and then the leaf nodes. 
Check the this [link](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/example/tree/two-trees.html) or below image to see how folder appears first and then the leaf node.

Is there any way to show the folders and leaf node order by name, instead of showing folders first. Or is there way to set some property for each folder and leaf node and then sort based on this property.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The configuration option which results in the sort behavior of the example you are referring to is [`folderSort`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore-cfg-folderSort). However, by default it is set to `false`, so you should not need to configure anything for your desired sort order.